# Feasible database testing

Tags: java, sql, database, unit-testing

I've been assigned with the task to investigate how we should perform our testing in an upcomming project.

Im currently trying to decide whenever or not we should have structured tests for our SQL statements. I've come to the conclusion that it might be a good idea to have test suits for the "get" statements to make sure that they return the correct data but not to test insert, delete or update since this can easily be verified with a select in the DB and foregin key exceptions will be thrown if some depedency is missing.

Now, i've been checking out `DBunit` to be used to perform these tests but I have a couple of conserns:

1.Is it feasible to perform tests as described above? Or is the time put to create these tests and insert test data not worth the effort? Pherhaps it's enough to let the developers test this ad-hoc?

2.It seems as it might be time consuming to decide on proper test data for each test. Test data should manually be inserted in the flat-xml-file that DBunit requires (if you let the expected data be generated by DBunit you are dependant on the SQL that fetches that data). Is this the case?

3.Is there a better, simpler way to perform database tests to verify SQL statements?

The project will be using Hibernate, Java and a MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

you can use dbunit or you can build the db content programatically (in each test). the important part is to let the testing framework (e.g. spring test) do the rollback after each test. once you setup the environment it's easy to test the DML done in a single transaction (get, insert, delete).

if you want to test DDL (some databases does that outside of a transaction) then you have to do manual rolling back or creating a database from scratch before each test (e.g. in memory db). DDL testing is usually not needed as hibernate does the validation part

and yes: you should test your queries - it's worth it to spend some time on preparing environment